# How to replace older D3js code that relies on d3.nest function to the newest version (v7) using d3.groups and js reduce

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to update some older D3js code that relies on `d3.nest` to the newest version (v7). This is an example of the raw data (from a csv) and the desired nested Object that I'm trying to achieve. Previously, this step relied on `d3.nest`

```
import * as d3 from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7.8.5/+esm";

var dummy;
var desired;

// example data from csv
dummy = [
  { variant: "0", year: "1950", mw: "m", pop: "31962", pop_0_4: "540" },
  { variant: "0", year: "1950", mw: "w", pop: "32052", pop_0_4: "545" },
  { variant: "0", year: "1951", mw: "m", pop: "31453", pop_0_4: "520" },
  { variant: "0", year: "1951", mw: "w", pop: "35444", pop_0_4: "526" },
  { variant: "1", year: "1950", mw: "m", pop: "41253", pop_0_4: "510" },
  { variant: "1", year: "1950", mw: "w", pop: "42356", pop_0_4: "515" },
  { variant: "1", year: "1951", mw: "m", pop: "45633", pop_0_4: "500" },
  { variant: "1", year: "1951", mw: "w", pop: "49500", pop_0_4: "501" },
];
console.log(dummy);

// desired format is an object I can reference using eg desired[1950].m[0][0]["pop_0_4"]
desired = {
  1950: {
    m: {
      0: [
        { variant: "0", year: "1950", mw: "m", pop: "31962", pop_0_4: "540" },
      ],
    },
    w: {
      0: [
        { variant: "0", year: "1950", mw: "m", pop: "32052", pop_0_4: "545" },
      ],
    },
  },
  1951: {
    m: {
      0: [
        { variant: "0", year: "1951", mw: "m", pop: "31453", pop_0_4: "520" },
      ],
    },
    w: {
      0: [
        { variant: "0", year: "1951", mw: "m", pop: "35444", pop_0_4: "526" },
      ],
    },
  },
  1950: {
    m: {
      0: [
        { variant: "1", year: "1950", mw: "m", pop: "41253", pop_0_4: "510" },
      ],
    },
    w: {
      0: [
        { variant: "1", year: "1950", mw: "m", pop: "42356", pop_0_4: "515" },
      ],
    },
  },
  1951: {
    m: {
      0: [
        { variant: "1", year: "1951", mw: "m", pop: "45633", pop_0_4: "500" },
      ],
    },
    w: {
      0: [
        { variant: "1", year: "1951", mw: "m", pop: "49500", pop_0_4: "501" },
      ],
    },
  },
};
console.log(desired);
console.log(desired[1950].m[0][0]["pop_0_4"]);

// In the old code this was done using
d3
  .nest()
  .key(function (d) {
    return d.year;
  })
  .key(function (d) {
    return d.mw;
  })
  .key(function (d) {
    return d.variant;
  })
  .map(csv)
```

This is where I've got to using `d3.groups` and js `reduce` but I can't work out how to convert the remaining nested arrays to objects. I want to be able to reference values in the final object as eg `desired[1950].m[0][0]["pop_0_4"]`

```
// my attempt - I can get close using d3.groups and reduce
// but I can't work out how to convert the remaining nested arrays to objects
var test;

test = d3
  .groups(
    dummy,
    (d) => d.year,
    (d) => d.mw,
    (d) => d.variant
  )
  .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let obj = {};
    curr[1].forEach((item) => (obj[item[0]] = item[1]));
    acc[curr[0]] = obj;
    return acc;
  }, {});
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use `d3.group`, rather than `d3.groups`, which returns nested [Map objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/), rather than nested arrays. As explained [in this section of the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps), Maps are very much like Objects but often preferable in the context of data storage and access.

Thus, you might try

```
grouped = d3.group(
  dummy,
  (d) => d.year,
  (d) => d.mw,
  (d) => d.variant
)
```

You could then access the data like so:

```
grouped.get("1950").get("m").get("0")[0].pop
```

Better yet, you could use `d3.rollup`, which is a lot like `d3.group` but provides a reducer to the final result. That would allow you to remove the superfluous `[0]` in your accessor. Thus:

```
rolled = d3.rollup(
  dummy,
  (A) => A[0],
  (d) => d.year,
  (d) => d.mw,
  (d) => d.variant
)
```

Then,

```
rolled.get("1950").get("m").get("1").pop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vanilla to reach your goal too.

```js
const sourceData = [
  { variant: "0", year: "1950", mw: "m", pop: "31962", pop_0_4: "540" },
  { variant: "0", year: "1950", mw: "w", pop: "32052", pop_0_4: "545" },
  { variant: "0", year: "1951", mw: "m", pop: "31453", pop_0_4: "520" },
  { variant: "0", year: "1951", mw: "w", pop: "35444", pop_0_4: "526" },
  { variant: "1", year: "1950", mw: "m", pop: "41253", pop_0_4: "510" },
  { variant: "1", year: "1950", mw: "w", pop: "42356", pop_0_4: "515" },
  { variant: "1", year: "1951", mw: "m", pop: "45633", pop_0_4: "500" },
  { variant: "1", year: "1951", mw: "w", pop: "49500", pop_0_4: "501" },
];
const desired = {};

sourceData.forEach(entry => {
  const year = entry.year;
  const mw = entry.mw;
  const variant = entry.variant;

  if (!desired[year]) {
    desired[year] = {};
  }

  if (!desired[year][mw]) {
    desired[year][mw] = {};
  }

  if (!desired[year][mw][variant]) {
    desired[year][mw][variant] = [];
  }

  desired[year][mw][variant].push(entry);
});


console.log(desired[1950].m[0][0]["pop_0_4"]);
console.log(desired); // The transformed data
```